# threading in python opens more thread then 1

Tags: python, multithreading

hello I am using threading in my python program

basically I am trying to get value from database and then analysis the value and then according to analysis write back to database

but when I do the same in threading it makes two threads instead of one and before analysis of one it does the same analysis in other one hance it makes one task two time

my code is as follows

```
def start_prog():
    while True:
        fer =mydb.cursor()
        sql="SELECT * FROM list"
        fer.execute(sql)
        data = fer.fetchall()
        for i in data:
            # do some take and update database
            print(i)
        fer.close()
        mydb.close()
ord_data = threading.Thread(target=start_prog)
ord_data.start()
```

please help

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to be using threads

Comment: @ForceBru I forgot to give here of starting thread code now updated